# Codeigniter: Querying databases returns multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to query database making a join between two tables.

In particular I have a list of docents and every docent has an Agenda with data and the hours are interspersed with an hour. So for example in the table

**Agenda**

```
id | docent_id | date       | start | end   |
1  |      1    | 2020-05-29 | 09:00 | 10:00 |
2  |      1    | 2020-05-29 | 10:00 | 11:00 |
3  |      2    | 2020-05-29 | 09:00 | 10:00 |
```

So I have in my controller:

```
public function docent_get()
    {
        $this->load->model('Docent_model');
        $result = $this->docent_model->getDocent();
        if (is_null($result)) {
            $this->response(null, 404);
            return;
        }
        $this->response($result, 200);

    }
```

and in my model:

```
public function getDocent()
    {
        $roles = 'Docent';
        $query = $this->db->select('Persons.id, Persons.name, Persons.surname, Agenda.date, Agenda.start_at, Agenda.end_at')
                ->from('Persons')
                ->join('Agenda', 'Persons.id = Agenda.docent_id', 'INNER')
                ->where('Agenda.free', 'true')
                ->where('roles', $roles)
                ->get();
        return $query->result();
```

Now this query works, but the result from this query for example is an array of three where the docent with the same id but different hours is repeated twice. In your opinion is it possible to change the answer 
so to get an array of two and in the case of the teacher with a multiple date have another array inside it? ( or something similar )

Because at the moment I have:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1", name: "name1", surname: "surname1", date: "2020-05-29", start: "09:00:00", end: "10:00:00"}
1: {id: "1", name: "name1", surname: "surname1", date: "2020-05-29", start: "10:00:00", end: "11:00:00"}
2: {id: "2", name: "name2", surname: "surname2", date: "2020-05-29", start: "09:00:00", end: "10:00:00"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below function to get expected answer:

```
public function getDocent()
    {
        $roles = 'Docent';
        $arr_return = array();
        $query = $this->db->select('Persons.id, Persons.name, Persons.surname, Agenda.date, Agenda.start, Agenda.end')
                ->from('Persons')
                ->join('Agenda', 'Persons.id = Agenda.docent_id', 'INNER')
                ->where('Agenda.free', 'true')
                ->where('roles', $roles)    
                ->get();
        $arr_result = $query->result_array();
        foreach($arr_result as $key=>$result)
        {
            if(!isset($arr_return[$result['id']]))
            $arr_return[$result['id']] = array('name'=> $result['name'], 'surname' => $result['surname']);

            $arr_return[$result['id']]['docent'][] = array('start'=> $result['start'], 'end'=> $result['end']);
        }

        //print_r($arr_return);
        return $arr_return;     
    }
```

Output will be like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sanjay
            [surname] => Surve
            [docent] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [start] => 09:00
                            [end] => 10:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [start] => 10:00
                            [end] => 11:00
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [surname] => Doe
            [docent] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [start] => 09:00
                            [end] => 10:00
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

*Note: You have to modify field names **(like start should be start_at)** as per your database.*

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Jack23 , Welcome :)  I’m happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate elements as follows

```
$done = array(); //checked ids
$output = array(); //final result
$n = 0;

foreach($result as $key){
   $key->start = array($key->start);
   $key->end = array($key->end);

   if(!in_array($key->id, $done){
       foreach(array_slice($n+1,$result) as $val){ //getting next part of the array
            if($val->id == $key->id){
                 $key->start[] = $val->start;
                 $key->end[] = $val->end;
            }
       }
       $output[] = $key;
   }
   $n++;
}

print_r($output)
```

Output should be

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1", name: "name1", surname: "surname1", date: "2020-05-29", start: ["09:00:00", "10:00:00"], end: ["10:00:00","11:00:00"]}
1: {id: "2", name: "name2", surname: "surname2", date: "2020-05-29", start: ["09:00:00"], end: ["10:00:00"]}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: I have tried in the controller but i receive the error: `Message: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)`

Comment: Sorry , Updated. `$key` should be replaced with `$result` in the second foreach.

Comment: SanjaySurve's answer is better. This is not a efficient solution.